# Center recyclerview vertical when few items

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView that takes up part of a ConstraintLayout. 
If it contains few items I need it to be centered vertically. (if the items doesn't fit on screen i need it to use the available space (matching the constraints)

I can get the wanted layout if is use layout_height="wrap_content" + layout_gravity="center_vertical", as long as all items fit in the available space.

But wrap_content doesn't work when the items need more space.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
  <FrameLayout
    android:id+"@+id/frameLayout"
    ...
  </FrameLayout>

  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout"
    tools:listitem="@layout/recyclerview_sections_items" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Try putting a fixed height to the adapter itself so that wrap_content doesn't clip them.

Comment: The problem isn't that the items get clipped but that the recyclerview covers other elements.

Comment: That was just a suggestion, not an answer to your problem. What do you mean by covers? From your layout, the `RecyclerView` is below everything which means it can't cover anything. And it's height is `0dp`, which means it's on `wrap_content`. You might have a constraint problem. Please post the whole layout.